# Exit file explorer in Vim without closing

Tags: vim

I have been trying to figure out how to exit the file explorer in Vim.

`:q` works, but it closes Vim as well, not just the file browser.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: :e works for me just fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The command `:bd` (delete current buffer) appears to close an active file explorer without closing Vim, even if the explorer is full-screen.

Answer (score 17):

This is expected behavior.

If you have an open modified file, `:Explore` will open a split-screen explorer, and typing `:q` will return to the opened file. If not, it will open a full-screen explorer, and `:q` will close vim.

If you want to force the split-screen explorer even when the opened file has not been modified, or if no file has been opened, use `:Sexplore` instead.

You can also use a tabbed full screen explorer with `:Texplore`, that probably behaves exactly the way you want. It will open the explorer on a new tab, and typing `:q` will always close that tab, but not vim.

Please take a look at [the Vim documentation about these commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#%3aExplore).

Comment: The problem with using `:Sexplore` is that the file is then opened in the split screen. This is the same with `:Texplore`.

Answer (score 12):

In Vim 8 (I haven't tried earlier versions) `:Rexplore` will work.

In `:help :Explore` it mentions:

```
:Rexplore            ... Return to/from Explorer
```

`:Rexplore` only actually works when you are in the Explorer.

`:Lexplore` is also a very nice option, as it will open the vertical explorer, but opening any file from there will open the file in your original window. Then you can close the explore window by typing `:Lexplore` again. This effectively then works similar to other file explorers like [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) or as in editors like Sublime Text. This is different behaviour from `:Sexplore` / `:Vexplore` / `:Texplore` which open the file in the same window as the Explorer.

Comment: I tried `:Lexplore` and it did not work like you said: doing `:Lex` after having opened the new file does not close the explore windows but a open a new one, and after doing `:q` several times to close everything I don't go back to the original file even if I made modifications on it (I lose them without the need of doing `:q!`).

Answer (score 1):

`:bd` work, but if you're open `NerdTree`, this will close `NerdTree` and with `:Rex`, everything works perfectly.